# Why does Z3 report different query statuses at web-page and locally (unsat/sat respectively)?

Tags: z3

http://rise4fun.com/Z3/MlnZ

The correct result should be UNSAT (online version), but locally Z3 3.2 reports SAT. It also produces an interesting [model](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r8x85hb4fsyr1yf/model.smt2), which contains a universe and cardinality constraints for enumeration types (datatypes). Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. Z3 3.2 does not install the recursive datatype engine for your script.
So, the sorts `Q` and `T` are treated as unintepreted sorts. 
Z3 4.0 fixes this bug. The online version is already running Z3 4.0. That is why you got the correct result with the online version.
You can use the following workaround in Z3 3.2.

> (set-option :auto-config false)

Comment: thanks! that works! the second issue - Z3 still doesn't simplify and return a concrete value of `(get-value ((tau t_0 i_stop))))` (for example). It produces: `(ite (= t_0 t_3) t_3 (ite (= t_0 t_2) t_0 (ite (= t_0 t_1) t_3 t_0)))))` which is just `t_0`. Ideas how to overcome?

Comment: This has been fixed in Z3 4.0. Are you still getting this kind of output in the online version? We should release Z3 4.0 this week.

Answer (score 2):

Wait is over. 4.0 has been released.